# zstyle, separate CDPATH completions from locals

Tags: zsh

Is there any way to separate CDPATH paths and local paths in zsh autocompletion? Ideally, to have something line this:

```
CDPATH="/foo/"

$ls /foo

foo1/ foo2/ foo3

$ls .
local1/ local2/ local-file

$cd <TAB>           << autocompletion...
local1/ local2/     << local dirs
                    << note blank line separating locals from CDPATH
foo1/ foo2/ foo3    << CDPATH
```

I tried playing with zstyle without much success:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:(cd|pushd):*' \
    tag-order 'local-directories named-directories path-directories'
```

**Related**:

- [How does the matcher-list arguments work in zsh zstyle completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906078/how-does-the-matcher-list-arguments-work-in-zsh-zstyle-completion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:(cd|pushd):*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*:complete:(cd|pushd):*' format ' '
```

Comment: I know this was long ago but can you expand on how one might actually do the formatting part?